# Nodejs crypto to Python jwt convert

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.7, cryptojs, python-cryptography

I'm doing an integration with a gateway and they provided me with a mechanism to create signature of some payload and I'm trying to convert this Nodejs code into python

here is the payload we want to sign:

```
actual = {"IntraTransferRqHeader": {"CorporateID": "XXX", "CorpReferenceNumber": "47165454456"},
                            "IntraTransferRqBody": {"AccountNumber": "05100004061100",
                                                    "DebitCurrency": "SAR", "BeneficiaryAccountNumber": "30008776337526",
                                                    "TransferAmount": "100.23",
                                                    "TransferCurrency": "SAR",
                                                    "Description": "Transfer fund to beneficiary", "AMLPurposeCode": "BC"}};
```

and here is the Nodejs provided code

```
const cert = fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/nginx/snbcsr.key', "utf8");

var privateKey = crypto.createPrivateKey({
    'key': cert,
    'format': 'pem',
});
var signerObject = crypto.createSign("RSA-SHA256");
signerObject.update(JSON.stringify(actual).trim());
var signature = signerObject.sign({ key: privateKey }, "base64");
```

and here is what i did to make the same signature

```
private_key_pem = "/etc/ssl/nginx/snbcsr.key"
with open(private_key_pem, "rb") as key_file:
   private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(key_file.read(), password=None, backend=default_backend())
signature = jwt.encode(actual, private_key, algorithm="RS256")
```

and i still get signature error. I don't know Nodejs and i don't know what am i doing wrong here

Comment: The Node.js code is not related to JWT at all.

Comment: good to know, what lib should simulate the same nodejs situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't confuse JWT with plain signing.

Given the Node.js code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cert = fs.readFileSync('key.pem', 'utf8');
var privateKey = crypto.createPrivateKey({
  'key': cert,
  'format': 'pem',
});
const payload = 'foople';
const signerObject = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
signerObject.update(payload);
const signature = signerObject.sign({key: privateKey}, 'base64');
console.log(signature);
```

the equivalent Python code, [using the `cryptography` library's signing primitives](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#signing), is

```
import base64

from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.padding import PKCS1v15
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import SHA256
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key

bk = default_backend()

with open("./key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
    private_key = load_pem_private_key(key_file.read(), password=None, backend=bk)

payload = b'foople'
signature = base64.b64encode(private_key.sign(
    payload,
    padding=PKCS1v15(),
    algorithm=SHA256(),
)).decode()
```

Given my freshly-generated mock 512-bit RSA key

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBPAIBAAJBAMd6HFNMreA1zwFpTA7vGFwSJFFZlKYtgJVsnSW3rc9zsisewUIC
U0MnvNucHeKifhniFOoimUr8hTiZMywEmFMCAwEAAQJBAJKYX+arzICgqr+rxZSY
C/vl7UDHp6G0gPHPP3HvmdGBNLst0mqV8GKbNEr1Myb7vQOjbYDno2OVFNL+jeMI
JYkCIQD2r+1dvpSDrSvelBIyymE1D42dQFviyoY8URCefRzJhQIhAM8B7VbcYNo1
Tm0BLCKIPO1CZKmPsYDb2byk8mtakVX3AiEAiDBF9iwh57Qx9PaAOYQbOGT2xKrk
T4eJpkEG0Mi3nNUCIQC6bdPf3E1ld4iP5vRmjSfBzX92rbCAin8Hw82HHWOydQIg
fLfsV/P5F0LseV5KRPVombYNc/bh4oU467kEEPXDX5w=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

both programs output

```
Wvy7cxuaUIpuiadTH2iOm6ayZUNrKY1whZElBIGBWbglEf0yA07wGbhD0qsPTWY7PzMtvuPV2xre+pCQsMwxmw==
```

Comment: i did what you suggested but it didn't work, still have the same issue with the verification error, also the base64 generated from js code is different from python for the same payload.

What is the meaning of the padding here ?

Comment: Both programs output the same base64 encoded signature for me. (See edit.)

Comment: it was my mistake, i have updated the code. it workx, how could i gain experience like that :) ?

Comment: Glad I could help. By working in the industry and learning as you go, that's what I've been doing...